# Prevent spam with Future.wait in flutter

Tags: flutter, future, spam, ddos

i have a anti DDOS rule in my server with max 20 requests in 1 second.

In my flutter program, i want to call an API n times but sometimes n is greater than 20.
How to avoid some issue

Here my code (don't work it seems)

```
      // Search token informations
      final tokenMap = <String, Token>{};
      var antiSpam = 0;
      final getTokens = await Future.wait(
        tokenAddressList.toSet().map((final tokenAddress) async {
          if (antiSpam > 0 && antiSpam % 19 == 1) {
            return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          } else {
            antiSpam++;
            return sl.get<ApiService>().getToken(
              [tokenAddress],
             
            );
          }
        }),
      );
```